# Thirteen Checkbox Selection for Multiple cases

Tags: excel, vba

My userform have around 13 checkbox to select department, each selection checkbox will then enter the value of the caption into the one single cell. Below code I test for 3 checkbox only, How to make it work for 13 checkbox?

```
If DeptCheckBox1.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = DeptCheckBox1.Caption

If DeptCheckBox2.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value & " " & DeptCheckBox2.Caption

If DeptCheckBox3.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value & " " & DeptCheckBox3.Caption
```

[image]

Comment: You are on the right track. Just keep checking the remaining 10 checkboxes, too. Two advices: you can omit `= True`. If you need to check this many objects you may put them in an array or a collection and check them in a loop.

Comment: Look into the [`Select case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement) statement.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through all `checkboxes` and capture selected boxes to a `String`. Then put that string to your `cell`.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ctl As Control
Dim AllCtl As String

    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" And ctl = True Then
            AllCtl = ctl.Caption & ", " & AllCtl
        End If
    Next ctl

Range("A1") = AllCtl
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way would be the next, I think:

1. Create a sub procedure (in the form code module) to be called by all the check Boxes (except the first one):

   `Private emptyrow as Long`

   `Private Sub changeVal(strCap As String)
       Cells(emptyrow, 8).Value = Cells(emptyrow, 8).Value & " " & strCap
   End Sub`
2. Use the `Change`event of all the check boxes in discussion in this way:

   `Private Sub DeptCheckBoxX_Click()
       If Me.DeptCheckBoxX.Value = True Then changeVal DeptCheckBoxX.Caption
   End Sub`

Where "X" is the text box number.

The field will be updated without pressing of any other control. Only `emptyrow` to be a variable declared of the module level and being well maintained...